# Simple Dimming equation help. Timer and Opacity

Tags: c#, winforms, math, timer

Hi at the beginning of my program I have a black form fade over my screen to simulate the illusion of the monitor turning off.  Anyway, I would like to be able to set the time (in milliseconds) it takes to dim onto, but I can't figure out the math. The timer's interval is 1ms. Here is the code I have already written I need to change the 0.005 to a variable.

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Opacity <= 0.999)
        {
            this.Opacity = this.Opacity + 0.005;
        }
        else
            timer1.Stop();
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use WPF. `<DoubleAnimation TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="00:00:00.5"/>`. winforms is u̶s̶e̶l̶e̶s̶s̶  very antiquated and is not intended to support rich UI experiences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your timer fires every X seconds (X=0.001), and your total opacity change is N (N = 1 - 0 = 1), and duration of effect is T (T = variable) your instant opacity change dX will be dX = N / (F * T), where F is a timer frequency, F = 1 / X.

Thus, `dX = N / (T * 1 / X) = N * X / T = 0.001 * T`